# which theme in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-7

I've been learning drupal for the last month.

Now I'd like to start with Themes. There are a lot of themes out there. My choice to start with is between Zen (for its popularity) and Omega (for it using 960gs).

What advices can I have in this?
Is Omega a better themer than Zen?. I think it is. Am I wrong?
What about the future (then its support) of Omega?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I you are at the beginning of the learning-curve, maybe you should look to Sky, also a 960 theme with html5 and much simpler then Omega or Zen.

Comment: I already did some theming tutorial.with Sky, as you said it is good for beginning.But now I'd like to go into the theme which will be my master theme for all my projets. I know they are a little bit more complicated but I think it will worth it.